# Simple syntax error in my while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

Hi doing some revising for an exam and came upon this past question.

Write a while loop to print the odd numbers between 0 and 10.
I've been toying about and trying to Google but its such a simple thing and its confusing me. I know its a simple syntax error somewhere.

I have tried moving the x++ about, tried moving the print statement about, just not getting it. can somebody shine light on this please. I would normally use a for loop as it would be easier but the question asks for a while loop.

```
public class OddNumbersWhile {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int x = 0;
        while (x <10){
            if (x % 2 !=0) {
                x++;
        System.out.println(x);
}} }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your closing braces on separate lines.

And here's the problem: You're incrementing `x` in your if-statement thus resulting in an infinite loop once the if-statement fails to trigger since your while condition cannot be reached.

This is probably closer to what you're after.

```
public class OddNumbersWhile {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int x = 0;
        while (x <10){
            if (x % 2 !=0) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i knew it was something simple, i was on the right lines, thanks for the advice with the braces. I cannot believe somebody down voted me for this. what a joke. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class OddNumbersWhile {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 10){
            if (x % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you define x = 0, when the while loop begins, you say:

```
if (x % 2 !=0)
```

but x % 2 is = 0, because x is 0, so x++ will never run.

P.S.

Ok, N0ir gave you the code. I was trying to bring you to the solution using logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `x++` outside of the if statement.

```
public class OddNumbersWhile {
public static void main (String[]args){
    int x = 0;
    while (x <10){
        if (x % 2 !=0) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        x++;
    }
  }
}
```